# jQuery: promises: 'always()' not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I am having trouble getting always() to fire on my Deferred in jQuery. done() and fail() work fine, but somehow I must be doing something wrong, because always() never fires.

With $.when it works...

```
var Validator = {
    validate_something: function(value) {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

        deferred.resolve();

        return deferred.promise();
    },

    validate_date: function(value) {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

        deferred.resolve();

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};


function doneCallback() {
    console.log("$.then.done() executed");
}

function failCallback() {
    console.log("$.then.fail() executed");
}

function alwaysCallback() {
    console.log("$.then.always() executed");
}

var validationPromise = $.when(
    Validator.validate_date(6).then(doneCallback, failCallback, alwaysCallback),
    Validator.validate_something(1).then(doneCallback, failCallback, alwaysCallback)
);

validationPromise.done(function() {
    console.log("$.when.done() executed");
});
validationPromise.fail(function() {
    console.log("$.when.fail() executed");
});
validationPromise.always(function() {
    console.log("$.when.always() executed");
});
​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6j6K2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: the constructor takes three arguments, but the last one is for progressCallbacks. You need to call always() separately.

```
var validate_date = Validator.validate_date(6).then(doneCallback, failCallback);
validate_date.always(alwaysCallback);

var validate_something = Validator.validate_something(1).then(doneCallback, failCallback);
validate_something.always(alwaysCallback);

var validationPromise = $.when(
    validate_date,
    validate_something
);
```

Comment: You'd better use `done`, `fail` and `progress` all the time. `then` is an alias to `pipe` as of `1.8.0` which means it's much much slower since it has to account for potentially convoluted scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have actually started doing that anyhow, because it results in much more readable code.